# How to close blackberry application programmatically?

Tags: blackberry

inside my blackberry application, i redirect the user to a predetermined website. before sending them to the website, i wanted to programatically close the application since there is no longer a need for that app to be open. what class or method can i use to close my application?

Answer (score 9):

```
System.exit(0);
```